# AADSTS650052 Error for OneNote in Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I've been integrating a multi-tenant Azure AD application including OneNote services and encountered a persistent error AADSTS650052, stating that my organization lacks a service principal for OneNote. The full error message was:

```
AADSTS650052: The app is trying to access a service '2d4d3d8e-2be3-4bef-9f87-7875a61c29de' (OneNote) 
that your organization '755d4acf-887e-46e7-8e1e-d34d4e28d545' lacks a service principal for. 
Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions 
or consent to the application in order to create the required service principal.
```

I tried several approaches suggested in the Microsoft documentation, but the error persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found a solution that resolved the issue. I simply logged into OneNote using the admin account for my Azure AD tenant.

This action seems to have triggered the setup for the OneNote service in my account, allowing me to complete the permission grant process successfully.

As a side note, I recall a very similar issue when adding new users to educational teams. In those cases, the notebook attached to the team wasn't available until the new member opened it directly from OneNote (or Teams).

That issue got me stuck for some hours when setting up a developer enviroment, I hope to save time to anyone going through the same process.